# Use a different NIC with packstack

Tags: openstack, packstack

I'm installing openstack in VirtualBox,

The VM has two NICs, a NAT one and a Host-Only one. Looks like `packstack` automatically selected the `NAT` one, which is unwanted.

```
10.0.2.15_prescript.pp:                              [ DONE ]
Applying 10.0.2.15_amqp.pp
Applying 10.0.2.15_mariadb.pp
10.0.2.15_amqp.pp:                                   [ DONE ]
10.0.2.15_mariadb.pp:                                [ DONE ]
```

Is there any way to change the NIC selected by `packstack`?

Answer (score 1):

This NAT IP that assigned is due to DHCP mentioned at NAT.  You can choose any IP you want by configuring a custom DHCP or Static IP.  In VirtualBox preferences,  go to Network and select NAT section and create a new NAT adapter and edit it as per your needs and save it.  Then select settings of your openstack VM and at network for NAT adapter choose the new adapter that you have created.

You need to shutdown the VM to apply these changes.

Let me know if any doubts.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking question about VirtualBox

Comment: But that is how your VM get IP,  please give a try.

Comment: The problem is you can't SSH to a NAT IP, which is why packstack must use the Host Only interface

Comment: @daisy You mean https://www.rdoproject.org/networking/neutron-with-existing-external-network/ ?

Comment: Probably, I'll take a look at it